# how to obtain the url about one recource(file.doc)

Tags: java, tomcat, url, web.xml

Suppose I have a file.doc in my maven web project.
I need to get the http url abount this file.doc The path is:

```
C:\Example\Book\resources\file.doc
```

Now I need to get the http url about this file, So I go in this path:

```
htpp://localhost:8080/Book/resources/file.doc
```

But I obtain 404 not found? Anyone can help me to understand how I get the http url about the resources?

Comment: There is no reason why the files on your disk would have an HTTP address unless you make it so there is a web server that decides to serve them.

Comment: Yes I use tomcat!

Comment: Tomcat won't magically give access to everything there is in your computer. If you want it to serve files, you need to tell it to in the ways it proposes.